# Call MS Studio C dll from Java JNA - error msg

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, visual-studio, runtime-error

**My hello.c file in MS Studio 2015 Win 10:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void hello();

void hello()
{
    printf("Hello from C");
}
```

**My Java file in eclipse:**

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

public class PaMMTE {

       public interface CPaMMTE_testDLL extends Library {
           public void welcome();
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           CPaMMTE_testDLL lib = (CPaMMTE_testDLL) Native.loadLibrary("TestCallingFromJava", CPaMMTE_testDLL.class);
           lib.welcome();
           System.out.println("Hello, World");
       }
}
```

*(The name of the dll is CPaMMTE_testDLL.)*

**Anyway, I've got the following error message:**

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: %1 is not a
> valid Win32 application.
> 
>   at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)   at
> com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:288)     at
> com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:427)     at
> com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:179)  at
> com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:569)   at
> com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:544)   at
> PaMMTE.main(PaMMTE.java:18)
```

I'm pretty sure that the configuration is wrong in MS Studio project. 
I've tried several different configurations without any good result.

I've changed on the MS Studio Win 10 configuration:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error
> looking up function 'hello': The specified procedure could not be
> found.
> 
>   at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:245)   at
> com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:566)     at
> com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:542)     at
> com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:528)     at
> com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:228)  at
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.hello(Unknown Source)   at
> PaMMTE.main(PaMMTE.java:14)
```

The second one looks better. :-)

My first problem was that I used 32-bit compile instead of 64 bit. But I still don't find the right MS config.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

Old pictures about the configuration are removed (I can add only two pic links).
The working MS Studio C configuration is:

[Create working MS Studio C dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu0TZ.jpg)

As I promised, I put here a working version (still not really understand why it is working).

**Java is the same!
C code:**

## include

```
__declspec(dllexport) void hello()
{
    printf("Hello from C");
}
```

Should I use extern? Or it is only relevant in case of c++ wrapping?

Comment: Please research how the C function should be named in order to match the Java package, class and method name.

Comment: Sorry, I've already changed to welcome to hello. I've tried several ways, and I copied the wrong function name. Sorry for this.

Comment: Now, it works. Tomorrow, I will give feedback to others! Thanks!

Comment: I've already added my solution and some question I would like to understand.

Comment: That error is usually caused due to 32/64 bit mismatch.

Comment: Yes, my first problem was 32/64 bit indeed. But now I have don't any problem, but I thought that I should use an extern keyword to make visible my method from outside and not __declspec(dllexport). So I'm a bit confused, what is the difference betweeen them and how can I use this logic in case of complex c++ libs. But at least I  have something working, thank for all of you!